# How to limit Upload file size php

Tags: php

I have the following php code, which allows user to upload an image. How can I modify my code so that there will be a limit (lets say maximun 20 k) to the size of the image uploaded. Here is my code.

```
<?php
/// another code ///
if($_POST)
{   

    if(!isset($_FILES['mFile']))
    {
        //required variables are empty
        die("Please add a image");
    }

    if($_FILES['mFile']['error'])
    {
        //File upload error encountered
        die(upload_errors($_FILES['mFile']['error']));
    }

    $FileName           = strtolower($_FILES['mFile']['name']);
    $auto                           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auto']);
    $FileType           = $_FILES['mFile']['type']; //file type
    $FileSize           = $_FILES['mFile']["size"]; //file size


            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mFile']["tmp_name"], $UploadDirectory . $NewFileName ))
         {


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, post, img_name) VALUES ('$FileTitle', '$postURL', '$NewFileName')");

        die('Thank you for your submission.');

   }else{
        die('There seems to be a problem. please try again.');
   }
}
/// another code ///
?>
```

Comment: 20K for an image? How small do you want them to be?

Comment: `if($_FILES["mFile"]["size"] < 90000){ //your code }`

Answer (score 1):

Set it like this

```
<?php
ini_set('post_max_size', '20K');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20K');
```

Comment: This will also cause `$_POST` to be empty if the upload is over 20K.

Comment: @Ben, That is correct. Thats why i had set `2MB` before , when `putvande` requested to change it as `20K`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

Programmatically:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '20K');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20K');
```

Via php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 20K
upload_max_filesize = 20K
```

Via .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20K
php_value post_max_size 20K
```

Comment: This will also cause `$_POST` to be empty if the upload is over 20K

Answer (score 1):

this a personal sample of use limit for pic size that uploaded, change table and vars

```
$picture = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
$picsize = $_FILES['pic']['size'];
$pictype = $_FILES['pic']['type'];

if(!empty($picture)){
        if(($pictype == 'image/gif') || ($pictype == 'image/jpeg') || ($pictype == 'image/pjpeg') || ($pictype == 'image/png') && ($picsize > 0) && ($picsize <= 30000 )){
            if($_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0)
                {
                $target = UPLOADPATH . $user_name;
                echo $target;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $target))
                {
                    $query2 = "UPDATE users SET profile_image = '{$user_name}' WHERE user_name = '{$user_name}'";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                }
                }
            else{
                echo 'upload failed';
            }


        }
        elseif(($pictype != 'image/gif') && ($pictype != 'image/jpeg') && ($pictype != 'image/pjpeg') && ($pictype != 'image/png')){
            echo 'incorrect file type';
        }
        elseif(($picsize <= 0) || ($picsize > 30000 ))
        {
            echo 'incorrect file size';
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

theres a setting in the php.ini where you can limit it. Some ppl use a hidden field for that purpose, but i dont like it tbh.